# PHPSpec: order of the class specs

Tags: php, phpspec

I'm developing a HTTP server and for the first time I've decided to write the <s>tests</s> specs with PHPSpec, which is great.

I have two spec classes: `spec\AppSpec` and `spec\RequestParserSpec`.

Since the `App` is the interface between the server components and the outer world, it uses the `RequestParser` to parse the requests. So, in order to get the specs in `AppSpec` passing, the `RequestParserSpec` has to be ran before to check if the request parsing is working fine.

Here is the problem : `$ phpspec run` runs before `AppSpec` and then `RequestParserSpec`.

Is it possible to inverse that order? Presently, if `RequestParser` has a problem, `AppSpec` will fail without telling what's the root problem.

Yes, I know I can do `phpspec run tests/spec/RequestParserSpec.php`, then the others, but it would be more practical if this could be automated to run the tests in one pass.

```
suites:
    myapp_suite:
        namespace: MyApp
        psr4_prefix: MyApp
        spec_path: tests
```

Comment: Can you please update question with the code for both classes and both specs?

Comment: Here are the specs : http://pastebin.com/5jQk5Rms and http://pastebin.com/7nTJ3VbE. Why are you interested in the sources?

Comment: Sorry, I see that Pastebin have broken my indentation on AppSpec, some lines are shifted...

Comment: To try and help you on how to spec them. Requiring a spec to run before another one means that you're probably not mocking/stubbing `RequestParser`.

Comment: Oh yes, that's perfectly true. This is the very first time I write tests so I'm not used to the different existing techniques and practices. `RequestParser` is an `EventEmitter` (mocking cannot handle this) and the code isn't built in a way that let me easily mimic a mocking (via calling directly `emit()` on the `RequestParser` for example.).
What do you think about this code? http://pastebin.com/iZcDMkd6

Answer (score 1):

You could substitute

```
$parser = new RequestParser(clone $this->baseRequest);
```

with this:

```
$parser = $this->requestParserFactory->createFromBaseRequest(clone $this->baseRequest);
```

then inject a RequestParserFactory, and you can then mock it in the spec.